# Converting GStreamer plugin from C to Rust yeilds different behavior with same base class

Tags: c, rust, gstreamer

I'm trying to convert [`ximagesrc`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/ximagesrc/index.html?gi-language=c) from C to Rust using [this code](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/blob/master/sys/ximage/gstximagesrc.c) as a base, but I'm getting different call behavior with my implementation that is derived from the same base class (`PushSrc`).

The original `ximagesrc` uses `set_caps` and `fixate` functions, but in my code those are never called. Instead, the `negotiate` function is called. Is this correct behavior? If so, how should I convert my current code to work in the same manner as the original?

`mod.rs`:

```rust
use gst::{glib, prelude::StaticType};

mod imp;

glib::wrapper! {
    pub struct XImageRedux(ObjectSubclass<imp::XImageRedux>) @extends gst_base::PushSrc, gst_base::BaseSrc, gst::Element, gst::Object;
}

impl Default for XImageRedux {
    fn default() -> Self {
        glib::Object::new(&[]).unwrap()
    }
}

unsafe impl Send for XImageRedux {}
unsafe impl Sync for XImageRedux {}


pub fn register(plugin: &gst::Plugin) -> Result<(), glib::BoolError> {
    gst::Element::register(
        Some(plugin),
        "ximageredux",
        gst::Rank::None,
        XImageRedux::static_type(),
    )
}
```

`imp.rs`:

```rust
use std::{sync::{Mutex, atomic::AtomicBool, Arc, MutexGuard}, time::Duration, ffi::CStr};

use derivative::Derivative;
use gst::{glib::{self, ffi::{G_LITTLE_ENDIAN, G_BIG_ENDIAN}}, subclass::prelude::{ObjectSubclass, ElementImpl, ObjectImpl, GstObjectImpl, ObjectImplExt}, prelude::{ToValue, ElementExtManual}, FlowError, error_msg};
use gst_app::prelude::BaseSrcExt;
use gst_base::{subclass::{prelude::{BaseSrcImpl, BaseSrcImplExt, PushSrcImpl}, base_src::CreateSuccess}, PushSrc};
use gst_video::ffi::{gst_video_format_from_masks, gst_video_format_to_string};
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
use anyhow::{Result, bail};
use xcb::{x::{GetGeometry, Drawable, GetImage, self, ImageOrder}, CookieWithReplyChecked, Connection};

use gst::gst_error as error;

pub static CAT: Lazy<gst::DebugCategory> = Lazy::new(|| {
    gst::DebugCategory::new(
        "ximageredux",
        gst::DebugColorFlags::empty(),
        Some("X11 Window Capture Engine"),
    )
});

type Xid = u32;

#[derive(Derivative)]
#[derivative(Default)]
struct State {
    connection: Option<xcb::Connection>,
    screen_num: Option<i32>,
    xid: Option<Xid>,
    #[derivative(Default(value="true"))]
    needs_size_update: bool,
    size: Option<Size>,
    frame_duration: Duration,
    resize_run: Option<Arc<AtomicBool>>
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct XImageRedux {
    state: Mutex<State>
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Size {
    width: u16,
    height: u16
}

impl XImageRedux {
    fn get_frame(&self) -> Result<gst::Buffer> {
        self.update_size_if_needed()?;

        let state = self.state.lock().unwrap();
        let (conn, xid) = get_connection(&state)?;

        let cookie = conn.send_request(&GetImage {
            format: x::ImageFormat::ZPixmap, // jpg
            drawable: xcb::x::Drawable::Window(unsafe { xcb::XidNew::new(xid) }),
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: state.size.as_ref().unwrap().width,
            height: state.size.as_ref().unwrap().height,
            plane_mask: u32::MAX,
        });

        let reply = wait_for_reply(conn, cookie)?;

        let mut buf = gst::Buffer::from_slice(reply.data().to_owned());
        let buf = buf.make_mut();
        buf.set_duration(gst::ClockTime::from_mseconds(state.frame_duration.as_millis() as u64));

        Ok(buf.to_owned())
    }

    // Function looks weird to get around mutex issues
    fn update_size_if_needed(&self) -> Result<()> {
        let should_update = {
            let mut state = self.state.lock().unwrap();

            if state.needs_size_update || state.size.is_none() {
                state.needs_size_update = false;
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        };

        if should_update {
            let new = self.get_size()?;
            let _ = self.state.lock().unwrap().size.insert(new);
        }

        Ok(())
    }

    fn get_size(&self) -> Result<Size> {
        let state = self.state.lock().unwrap();
        let (conn, xid) = get_connection(&state)?;
        
        let cookie = conn.send_request(&GetGeometry {
            drawable: Drawable::Window(unsafe { xcb::XidNew::new(xid) })
        });

        let reply = wait_for_reply(conn, cookie)?;

        Ok(Size {
            width: reply.width(),
            height: reply.height()
        })
    }

    fn open_connection(&self) -> Result<()> {
        let mut state = self.state.lock().unwrap();

        let (connection, screen_num) = match xcb::Connection::connect(None) {
            Ok((c, s)) => (c, s),
            Err(e) => bail!("Failed to connect to X11 server: {}", e.to_string())
        };

        let _ = state.connection.insert(connection);
        let _ = state.screen_num.insert(screen_num);

        Ok(())
    }

    unsafe fn get_video_format(&self) -> Result<i32> {
        let state = self.state.lock().unwrap();
        let (conn, xid) = get_connection(&state)?;

        let setup = conn.get_setup();
        let mut endianness = match setup.bitmap_format_bit_order() {
            ImageOrder::MsbFirst => G_BIG_ENDIAN,
            ImageOrder::LsbFirst => G_LITTLE_ENDIAN
        };

        let cookie = conn.send_request(&GetGeometry {
            drawable: Drawable::Window(xcb::XidNew::new(xid))
        });

        let geometry_reply = wait_for_reply(conn, cookie)?;

        let bpp = setup.pixmap_formats().iter().find(|fmt| fmt.depth() == geometry_reply.depth()).unwrap().bits_per_pixel();

        let screen = setup.roots().nth(state.screen_num.unwrap() as usize).unwrap();

        let visual = screen.allowed_depths()
            .flat_map(|depth| depth.visuals().into_iter())
            .find(|vis| vis.visual_id() == screen.root_visual())
            .unwrap();

        // Our caps system handles 24/32bpp RGB as big-endian
        let (red_mask, green_mask, blue_mask) = if (bpp == 24 || bpp == 32) && endianness == G_LITTLE_ENDIAN {
            endianness = G_BIG_ENDIAN;
            let mut set = (visual.red_mask().to_be(), visual.green_mask().to_be(), visual.blue_mask().to_be());

            if bpp == 24 {
                set.0 >>= 8;
                set.1 >>= 8;
                set.2 >>= 8;
            }

            set
        } else {
            (visual.red_mask(), visual.green_mask(), visual.blue_mask())
        };

        let alpha_mask = if bpp == 32 {
            !(red_mask | green_mask | blue_mask)
        } else {
            0
        };

        Ok(gst_video_format_from_masks(geometry_reply.depth().into(), bpp.into(), endianness, red_mask, green_mask, blue_mask, alpha_mask))
    }
}

fn wait_for_reply<C>(conn: &Connection, cookie: C) -> Result<C::Reply> 
    where C: CookieWithReplyChecked 
    {
        match conn.wait_for_reply(cookie) {
            Ok(reply) => Ok(reply),
            Err(e) => bail!("Failed to wait for X reply: {}", e)
        }
}

fn get_connection<'a>(state: &'a MutexGuard<State>) -> Result<(&'a xcb::Connection, Xid)> {
    let xid = match state.xid {
        Some(xid) => xid,
        None => bail!("XID is not set!"),
    };

    Ok((state.connection.as_ref().unwrap(), xid))
}

#[glib::object_subclass]
impl ObjectSubclass for XImageRedux {
    const NAME: &'static str = "XImageRedux";
    type Type = super::XImageRedux;
    type ParentType = PushSrc;
}

impl PushSrcImpl for XImageRedux {
    fn create(
            &self,
            element: &Self::Type,
            buffer: Option<&mut gst::BufferRef>,
        ) -> Result<CreateSuccess, gst::FlowError> {
        // Check if time for next frame
        
        
        if let Err(e) = self.update_size_if_needed() {
            error!(CAT, "Failed to resize: {}", e.to_string());
            return Err(gst::FlowError::Error);
        }

        // {
        //     let state = self.state.lock().unwrap();
        //     buffer.set_size(state.size.as_ref().unwrap().width as usize * state.size.as_ref().unwrap().height as usize * 3);
        // }

        let frame = match self.get_frame() {
            Ok(f) => f,
            Err(e) => {
                error!(CAT, "Failed to get frame: {}", e.to_string());
                return Err(FlowError::Error);
            }
        };

        Ok(CreateSuccess::NewBuffer(frame))
    }
}

impl BaseSrcImpl for XImageRedux {
    fn caps(&self, element: &Self::Type, _filter: Option<&gst::Caps>) -> Option<gst::Caps> {
        if self.state.lock().unwrap().connection.is_none() {
            if let Err(e) = self.open_connection() {
                error!(CAT, "Failed to open connection: {}", e);
                return Some(element.pad_template_list()[0].caps())
            }
        }

        if let Err(e) = self.update_size_if_needed() {
            error!(CAT, "Failed to update size: {}", e.to_string());
            return None;
        }

        let fmt = match unsafe { self.get_video_format() } {
            Ok(fmt) => fmt,
            Err(e) => {
                error!(CAT, "Failed to get video format: {}", e.to_string());
                return None;
            }
        };

        let c_str: &CStr = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(gst_video_format_to_string(fmt)) };

        let state = self.state.lock().unwrap();
        let size = state.size.as_ref().unwrap();

        Some(gst::Caps::new_simple("video/x-raw", &[
            ("format", &c_str.to_str().unwrap()),
            ("width", &(size.width as i32)),
            ("height", &(size.height as i32)),
            ("framerate", &(gst::FractionRange::new(gst::Fraction::new(0, 1), gst::Fraction::new(i32::MAX, 1))))
        ]))
    }

    fn set_caps(&self, _element: &Self::Type, caps: &gst::Caps) -> Result<(), gst::LoggableError> {
        println!("Set caps");
        if self.state.lock().unwrap().connection.is_none() {
            return Err(gst::LoggableError::new(*CAT, glib::BoolError::new("Not ready!", "imp.rs", "set_caps", 0)));
        }

        let framerate: gst::Fraction = match caps.structure(0).unwrap().value("framerate").unwrap().get() {
            Ok(f) => f,
            Err(e) => return Err(gst::LoggableError::new(*CAT, glib::BoolError::new(format!("Error: {}", e.to_string()), "imp.rs", "set_caps", 0)))
        };

        self.state.lock().unwrap().frame_duration = Duration::from_millis(1000 * framerate.denom() as u64 / framerate.numer() as u64);

        Ok(())
    }

    // fn negotiate(&self, element: &Self::Type) -> Result<(), gst::LoggableError> {
    //     println!("Negotiate");
    //     let caps = element.pads()[0].query_caps(None);

    //     if self.state.lock().unwrap().connection.is_none() {
    //         return Err(gst::LoggableError::new(*CAT, glib::BoolError::new("Not ready!", "imp.rs", "set_caps", 0)));
    //     }

    //     let framerate: gst::Fraction = match caps.structure(0).unwrap().value("framerate").unwrap().get() {
    //         Ok(f) => f,
    //         Err(e) => return Err(gst::LoggableError::new(*CAT, glib::BoolError::new(format!("Error: {}", e.to_string()), "imp.rs", "set_caps", 0)))
    //     };

    //     self.state.lock().unwrap().frame_duration = Duration::from_millis(1000 * framerate.denom() as u64 / framerate.numer() as u64);

    //     Ok(())
    // }

    // fn event(&self, element: &Self::Type, event: &gst::Event) -> bool {
    //     println!("EVENT");
    //     true
    // }

    fn fixate(&self, element: &Self::Type, mut caps: gst::Caps) -> gst::Caps {
        let caps = caps.get_mut().unwrap();

        for i in 0..caps.size() {
            caps.structure_mut(i).unwrap().fixate_field_nearest_fraction("framerate", gst::Fraction::new(25, 1));
        }

        self.parent_fixate(element, caps.to_owned())
    }

    fn start(&self, _element: &Self::Type) -> Result<(), gst::ErrorMessage> {
        if let Err(e) = self.open_connection() {
            Err(error_msg!(
                gst::ResourceError::Failed,
                [&e.to_string()]
            ))
        } else {
            Ok(())
        }
    }

    fn stop(&self, _element: &Self::Type) -> Result<(), gst::ErrorMessage> {
        self.state.lock().unwrap().connection.take();

        Ok(())
    }
}

impl ElementImpl for XImageRedux {
    fn metadata() -> Option<&'static gst::subclass::ElementMetadata> {
        static ELEMENT_METADATA: Lazy<gst::subclass::ElementMetadata> = Lazy::new(|| {
            gst::subclass::ElementMetadata::new(
                "X11 Window Capture Engine",
                "Source/Video",
                "Captures X11 windows",
                "Jack Hogan",
            )
        });

        Some(&*ELEMENT_METADATA)
    }

    fn pad_templates() -> &'static [gst::PadTemplate] {
        static PAD_TEMPLATES: Lazy<Vec<gst::PadTemplate>> = Lazy::new(|| {
            let caps = gst::Caps::builder_full()
                .structure(gst::Structure::builder("video/x-raw")
                    .field("framerate", gst::FractionRange::new(gst::Fraction::new(0, 1), gst::Fraction::new(i32::MAX, 1)))
                    .field("width", gst::IntRange::new(0, i32::MAX))
                    .field("height", gst::IntRange::new(0, i32::MAX))
                    .build()
                ).build();

            let src_pad_template = gst::PadTemplate::new(
                "src",
                gst::PadDirection::Src,
                gst::PadPresence::Always,
                &caps,
            )
            .unwrap();

            vec![src_pad_template]
        });

        PAD_TEMPLATES.as_ref()
    }
}

impl ObjectImpl for XImageRedux {
    fn properties() -> &'static [glib::ParamSpec] {
        static PROPERTIES: Lazy<Vec<glib::ParamSpec>> = Lazy::new(|| {
            vec![
                glib::ParamSpecString::builder("xid")
                    .nick("XID")
                    .blurb("XID of window to capture")
                    .build()
            ]
        });

        PROPERTIES.as_ref()
    }

    fn set_property(&self, _obj: &Self::Type, _id: usize, value: &glib::Value, pspec: &glib::ParamSpec) {
        match pspec.name() {
            "xid" => match value.get::<String>().unwrap().parse::<Xid>() {
                Ok(xid) => {
                    let mut state = self.state.lock().unwrap();
                    let _ = state.xid.insert(xid);
                    state.needs_size_update = true;
                }
                Err(e) => panic!("Failed to parse XID from String: {}", e),
            }
            _ => unimplemented!()
        }
    }

    fn property(&self, _obj: &Self::Type, _id: usize, pspec: &glib::ParamSpec) -> glib::Value {
        match pspec.name() {
            "xid" => self.state.lock().unwrap().xid.unwrap_or(0).to_value(),
            _ => unimplemented!()
        }
    }

    fn constructed(&self, obj: &Self::Type) {
        self.parent_constructed(obj);
        obj.set_live(true);
        obj.set_format(gst::Format::Time);
    }
}

impl GstObjectImpl for XImageRedux {}
```

Input command:

```
GST_DEBUG=4 RUST_BACKTRACE=1 GST_PLUGIN_PATH=`pwd`/target/debug/ gst-launch-1.0 --verbose ximageredux xid=44040202 ! queue ! ximagesink
```

Output: https://pastebin.com/KkpGVhBq

Comment: The code above works fine for me with GStreamer 1.16 and 1.20 and gstreamer-rs 0.18. I think your problem is simply that negotiation with ximagesink does not work. Try using fakesink or videoconvert ! pngenc snapshot=true ! filesink location=test.png or similar.

negotiate() is by default calling into fixate() and set_caps(), and does here for me.

Comment: I used both of the commands you listed and they work fine. Is there something else I could be doing wrong or not doing at all that is breaking `ximagesink`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a format incompatibility that manifested itself as a negotiation error. The original element outputted `RGBx` video whereas my element outputted `RGBA`. Adding a `videoconvert` element into the pipeline fixed the issue.